# Oracle Linux hang

Tags: linux

I am pretty new to Linux, and I am using Oracle Linux 5.6.64.1. Recently, I encounter the system hang frequently. I would like to know how I could troubleshoot the problem.

Updated

Downvoted twice, so I guess something wrong with my question? But as I said, I am new to linux, and can't really provice any further information. I read from some forum that I should check /var/log/messages, so I did. But frankly speaking, I can't conclude anything from the log. The system just hangs, and no error or messages on console.

Comment: Do you have any other information about the issue?  What's the server run?  Are there any logs or messages on the console when this occurs?

Comment: Take a peek at [ask].

Comment: It just hang. There is no messeages on the console. As I mentioned in my question, I am pretty new to linux, so I have no idea where to start looking for log.

Comment: `/var/log/messages` is a good starting point.

Comment: But what should I be looking for in /var/log/messages?

Comment: We can't really help you as you lack the requisite skills to help us. Speak to your manager about getting some basic training - you need it more than a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most people would suggest, look at `/var/log/messages`. What you're looking for are messages that occur in and around the time the system 'hangs'. If you don't find anything obvious, look in other log files for clues. Most Linux variants log just about EVERYTHING (usually in `/var/log/messages`). Some things may not be obvious at first and you may have to do some searching for messages that appear out of the 'ordenary'.

Also, if you are using Linux over an SSH or other remote connection and are encountering hangs, it is likely network latency.

Answer (score 0):

How hung is the system? Can you ping it? If there is an attached keyboard, does the light come on when you press the caps-lock key?

Does the hang always happen at or around the same time of day? Check for cron jobs occurring at that time.

Does last show the same users logged in? Ask what they were doing.

Do hangs occur at roughly the same time after a reboot? Your system may be overheating: check fans and cooling.

Check your hardware. Make sure memory dimms and cards are properly seated. Run memory tests, and any other hardware diagnostics that come with the system (check the vendor's web site). Check bios settings.

Carefully read boot messages, looking for anything that might indicate a problem.